# Magento : How to change catalog product layout view by code?

Tags: magento

My catalog product use 3 Columns Layout. The layered navigation in the right The product in the center The cart in the left. my problem when i don't have a product in the category the right column is empty. I wish when my category is empty ma catalog product transform from 3 columns to 2 columns. Can i do that by code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

`$product->setPageLayout('two_columns_right');`  // two_columns_left or one_column

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own module (I named it "ProductTemplate") There you can use an event:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_load_before>
            <observers>
                <yournamespace_producttemplate>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yournamespace_producttemplate/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductLoadBefore</method>
                </yournamespace_producttemplate>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

And in your observer-class you can update the template within your method as followed:

```
class Yournamespace_ProductTemplate_Model_Observer {

  public function catalogProductLoadBefore (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setPageLayout('two_columns_left');
  }
}
```